# Use Flask to serve both static CSS and static video files

Tags: python, flask

I set up a Flask server to render raw MP4 videos. I can play the videos stored outside my Flask project folder by setting `app = Flask(__name__, static_folder=<video_folder>)`. But this will cause Flask to fail to find the CSS files stored inside the project folder for the website. Any solution to solve both? 'static_folder' cannot be a list.

Comment: Right now, my solution is to move the not-so-many CSS into base.html and mount the ```static_folder``` to the video folder

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your video folder should be inside the 'static' folder, and you should have your URLs to videos point to 'static/video/file.mov' etc. You can use `url_for` to make sure the hrefs are constructed properly. See https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/tutorial/static/ and https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/quickstart/#url-building

If you cannot move the files for some reason, you can use `send_from_directory` in your route to do what you're describing:

```
app.route('/uploads/<path:filename>')
def download_file(filename):
    return send_from_directory(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'],
                               filename, as_attachment=True)
```

See https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/api/#flask.send_from_directory

Comment: Thanks, Matt for the prompt reply. The problem is the video folder is large and is maintained by other services. The Flask server is used to handle queries and return one video at a time.